# Zend 2: Model table from view helper error

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm having a problem with setting up a model table from a view helper. I have used the exact same code that I use within my regular controllers: e.g.:

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

use Application\Model\MenusTable;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;  
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface; 

**snipped**

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)  
{  
    $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;  
    return $this;  
}

public function getServiceLocator()  
{  
    return $this->serviceLocator;  
} 

public function getMenusTable()
{
    if (!$this->menusTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->menusTable = $sm->get('Application\Model\MenusTable');
    }

    return $this->menusTable;
}

public function allLinks()
{
    $all = $this->getMenusTable()->fetchAll();

    return $all;
}
```

However I am met with this error:

`Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Model\MenusTable::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, none given, called in C:\xampp\**snipped**\zend\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 177 and defined in C:\xampp\**snipped**\Application\src\Application\Model\MenusTable.php on line 14`

Everything works fine from the main controllers, but here I seem to hit a big problem - I'm new to Zend, but it appears to not be getting the factory from the Module.php file - is there any way to get it?

I have this in my Module.php - as said it works fine in a regular controller, but in a view helper it's not processed for some reason:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array
    (
        'factories' => array
        (
            'Application\Model\MenusTable' => function($sm)
            {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table     = new MenusTable($dbAdapter);
                return $table;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your question I realized that your using ZF2.

here is a tutorial on using ServiceLocators http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Proposal+for+ServiceLocator+and+DependencyInjector

From the Documentation you need to define your DB connection.

```
$services = new ServiceLocator();

// Registering an object:
$services->set('db', $db);

// Lazy-loading by registering a closure:
$services->set('db', function() use ($config) {
$db = Db::factory($config->db);
    return $db;
});

// Retrieving:
$db = $services->get('db');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use the getServiceConfig() in your module ::

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MODULE\Model\MenusTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('MenusTableGateway');
                $table = new MenusTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'MenusTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Menus());
                return new TableGateway('menus', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

THE ADAPTER might be in your /config/autoload/global.php, like this :

```
    'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
),
// CONNECTION DB
'db' => array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=YOURDBNAME;host=localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),
```

Next your View helper must extend AbstractHelper but also implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface

`class MyViewHelper extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`

I'll put the code in my [website](http://patricia-lestrat.com/zf2)